# Straightforward way to verify uniqueness of an IEnumerable elements

Tags: .net

Having a simple `IEnumerable` of `Integer` values, what's the simpler way to verify that all elements are unique?

Comment: Do you mean `IEnumerable<Int32>`?

Comment: Precisely.  But I don't like to narrow the audience to C#.

Comment: By having C# primary language of .NET I think it's fine to use its syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare count of unique elements with total count:

```
sequence.Distinct().Count() == sequence.Count();
```

Note that it will enumerate your sequence 2-3 times.

Comment: I just think about it.